# Are Spring boot 2.2.x apps deployable to Servlet 3.0 containers

Tags: spring-boot, servlets

I didn't find enough documentation on spring-boot and Servlet Container compatability. What should be the minimum Servlet specification implementation required for deploying Spring-boot 2.2.x apps?

Answer (score 1):

as written in the documentation of Spring boot 2.2.0.RELEASE on page 4-5.

*'You can also deploy Spring Boot applications to any Servlet 3.1+ compatible container.'*

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/pdf/spring-boot-reference.pdf